# Login with Box account

Tags: oauth, box-api

Is it possible to implement a "login with your Box account" feature similar to what we have with Facebook and others oauth providers?

I've tried to build something like that following [Box's oauth tutorial](http://developers.box.com/oauth/), but every time the user authenticates, it asks not only for login and password but also for granting access for my application even if the app has been already granted access.

Is there a way to make Box remember that the user has already granted access for my application?

Comment: I also have the same issue with kerika (https://kerika.com). Currently we are providing login into app using google, but now are are going to support the same feature for Box. But, when we deployed the app on our test server we noticed that each time user wants to use kerika she needs to pass through the screen where Box asks for authorization to the application (Google calls this screen as user-consent screen).

In this manner, google is really good. They just present the user consent screen to the user on very first login.

Is there any plan to update this behavior?

Comment: Box has the same kind of user-consent screen logic, where we only present it when a user actually logs in. It sounds like you are logging the user out, and then logging them back in.  Have you considered not logging the user out all the time.  Totally reasonable idea for us to consider to remember the user's consent response, and skip the consent screen on re-login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to be possible: I have been in touch with Box's Product and Platform team and this is the response I got:

> It's unlikely that we're going to support persistent login in the near future. This is related to our implementation of OAuth2. It's possible for clients to have their secrets hijacked, and requiring a handshake request with that secret plus a one-time auth token provides added security.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely under Box's control. They currently force you to go through the authentication process every time and there's no way around this.

Your best bet is to post something to the developer forum and ask them if they can remember if a logged in user as approved your app and skip the authentication process.

http://developers.box.com/forum/

Comment: I'm not sure your comment makes sense. Logged in users are remembered just fine in Box applications.  It sounds like you are asking Box to remember sessions for you, instead of your application managing sessions.  Box sessions can last indefinitely, as long as you manage them properly.  Box has Auth Tokens and Refresh tokens.  If you use the refresh token, your users aren't forced to re-login, and they won't see the consent screen other than the first time.  Unless you aren't managing tokens...

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure you understand the question or my answer

Comment: I think I don't understand what you mean in your question. Box does not currently remember approval between logins, but if someone stays logged in, then your statement: "if they can remember if a logged in user as approved your app and skip the authentication process" doesn't make sense.  A logged in user is logged in, and remembered, including their approval of the app. The only time you have to re-approve an app is if you log out, or logon on a different device (with the same app).